# Commit error with EventStore

Tags: cqrs, neventstore

I am seeing the following error in Jonathon Oliver's EventStore :

**ERROR: 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ix_commits_revisions"**

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the index is as I googled it:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Commits_Revisions ON Commits (
     StreamId, StreamRevision, Items);
```

Two `Save`s have written equivalent changes, which represents an optimistic concurrency violation.

Typically this would be converted by a Common Domain (or similar) layer to an EventStore `ConcurrencyException`.

The solution is to re-apply the Command against a fresh Load of the events in the stream.

If you are caching the `IEventRepository`, you shouldn't be as everyone with write access to the database can equally write into the event stream.

How do I know all this? The Readme documents in the NuGet package explain the basis behind this very clearly and you're stealing from yourself/your employer if you don't read and re-read them until you can work this out yourself!